# Hiding the ends of a fixed width jquery carousel div on different page sizes

Tags: html, css, jquery-plugins, jcarousel

I'm not even sure what I am asking for is possible, so could use some expert advice.

http://proof.jiujitsu.co.za/index.html

I have a fixed width div containing a jquery carousel.

The carousel is wider than the main page content.

When the page is loaded on a smaller resolution screen (eg 1280 x 1024 ) the rest of the page shifts as expected but obviously the carousel div does not.

Is it possible 'move' the carousel so that the middle three un-masked images stay in line with the rest of the page content and the two outer masked images dissapear off screen.

If it is possible, where would I start, js or css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the following:

```
.slider_layout {
    width: 1605px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

To the following:

```
.slider_layout {
    width: 1605px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -802px;
}
```

Which will keep your carousel centred at any resolution.

Comment: Awseome, that works. Thanks very much! It still 'breaks' when the resolution is smaller than the 960 width of the main content, but thats to be expected. Thanks again for your help.